# Angular js not updating local files

Tags: angularjs

I had my angular app running fine last night, after opening back up tonight, the app runs, but changes made on my files i.e `store.controller.js` and `store.html` no longer take effect all the time.

For example:

```
<h1>{{product.name}}</h1> 

from 

var item = [{
    name: 'Shoe'
}]
```

Should output "Shoe". Though, it doesn't, it'll list an old variable. Which was 'Find Me'.

It's no longer updating from the controller properly. Any ideas? I can list more code if preferred.

```
//store.html 
<div class="store-block">
  <div ng-repeat="product in products" ng-show="product.canPurchase" class="item-panel">
    <h1 class="pull-left">No expression</h1>
    <h2 class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</h2>
    <div class="product-image clearfix">
      <img ng-src="{{product.images[0]}}" />
    </div>
    <section>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right clearfix">
        <li> <a ng-click="panelCtrl.isSelected(1)" href>Help</a></li>
        <li> <a href>Colors</a></li>
        <li> <a href>Reviews</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="panel">
        <h3>Description</h3>
        <span class="pull-right" ng-hide="desc.element">{{product.category}}</span>
        <span class="pull-right" ng-hide="desc.element">Stock {{product.stock}}</span>
        <p class="clearfix" ng-hide="desc.element">{{product.description}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel" >
        <h3>Colors</h3>
        <p>{{product.colors[0]}}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  </section>
</div>
</div>
```

store.controller.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularStoreApp')
  .controller('StoreCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

  var item = [
   {
    name:  'Hello',
    price: 3.52,
    description: 'Hi  soulless creaturas, imo monstra adventus vultus comedat cerebella viventium. Qui offenderit rapto, terribilem incessu.',
    category: 'Sandels',
    stock: 1,
    canPurchase: true,
    images: [
      "assets/images/yeoman.png",
      "http://billypurvis.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ACTA.png"

    ],
    colors: [
      //Add image"Blue",
      //Add image"Brown"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Shoe 2',
    price: 4.56,
    description: 'Zombies reversus ab inferno, nam malum cerebro. De carne animata corpora quaeritis. Summus sit​​, morbo vel maleficia? De Apocalypsi undead dictum mauris.',
    category: 'Tie up',
    stock: 32,
    canPurchase: true,
    images: [
      "http://billypurvis.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ACTA.png"
    ],
    colors: [
      //Add image"Blue",
      //Add image"Brown"
    ]
  }
];
 $scope.products = item;
});
```

The out put still results in 'Hello', when it shouldn't even be output anywhere. I've cleared my cache, saved all the files, restarted grunt serve. Any one have any ideas?

If it helps, I'm using Webstorm IDE.

Comment: you definitely haven't listed enough code here to even guess as to where your problem might be.

Comment: Please provide some more code

Comment: Uncompiled brace syntax usually only appears when there's a compilation error. Does anything show up in the console?

Comment: I can get some code in a minute. An update though, removing the entire contents of store.controller.js and restarting grunt server, the page still loads all of the 'old' data.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind while working with angularJS is to clear the cache and try them. Because you make the right change, then check it, it works. Then you come back , change it again and run the application and it would still work since the data is sitting in the DOM. So clear the cache every time before and after your changes.

also use your browser debugger(console) to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found that viewing my app in a Chrome Incognito window ensured the files were being loaded afresh from my localhost on every refresh.

Answer (score -1):

I had previously duplicated the controller file resulting in two copies of:

- store.controller.js
- store.html
- store.js

This meant I was editing either store.controller.js in the duplicate folder of the original store directory (containing the listed files) and then editing store.html in the original store directory. Or visa versa. This causes issues with files 'overlapping' each other.

Removing the duplicate files (the copied directory) removed this issue.

Edit: Added More Information.

Comment: its weird. This can be one of the reason, not too sure. But always clear cache everytime before you test.

Comment: Yeah, I shall keep it in mind! It wasn't a complete waste, it stumped me and another developer and I learnt a few bits on the way anyhow. Oh well, an hour wasted. 

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a more detailed answer that shows how you solved your problem--this might be useful to someone with a similar issue.

Comment: Answer has been updated. I figured stating the duplicates were an issue gave anyone with an ounce of common sense the idea to remove the duplicates.